# Understanding proof of continuity of partial derivative

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I have trouble understanding the general concept of how to prove the continuity of the partial derivative (I will here use the continuity definition via limits of sequences). May be someone can give me a quick feedback on my thoughts:

If I take the partial derivative of a function $f$ two things might happen:

1.) The function is simply a compostion of differentiable functions and **not piece-wise** defined, say $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f{x \choose y}=x^2+xy^2$. So applying the rules of differentiation yields the partial derivative w.r.t $x$: $D_xf=2x+y^2$. If I check for continuity I plug in an arbitrary point ${x \choose y}$ into $D_xf{x \choose y}$ and afterwards I check if for any convergent sequence $lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n \choose y_n}= {x \choose y}$ it holds $D_xf{x \choose y}=lim_{n \to \infty}D_xf{x_n \choose y_n}$. Or I simply argue that $2x+y^2$ is a composition of continuous functions which also is continuous. This, I would regard as the "standard" case.

2.) However, I get confused when the function $f$ **is piece-wise** defined, as this almost always means that there are boundary points, say ${1 \choose 1}$, were you cannot simply apply the rules of differentiation but must check the limit. Let's assume a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$g{x \choose y}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} x^2+xy^2, & {x \choose y} \neq {1 \choose 1} \\
         2, & {x \choose y} = {1 \choose 1}\end{array},\right.  $$ 
Let the partial w.r.t. $x$ at ${1 \choose 1}$ be: $D_xg{1 \choose 1}= lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2+x1^2-2}{x-1}= 3$. Applying the rules of differentiation yields the partial for all other points except ${1 \choose 1}$ is: $D_xg{x \choose y}=2x+y^2$.

If I now want to check for continuity of the partial at point ${1 \choose 1}$ then for any convergent sequence $lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n \choose y_n}= {1 \choose 1}$ which I plug in into $D_xg{x \choose y}=2x+y^2$ it must hold $D_xg{1 \choose 1}=3=lim_{n \to \infty}D_xg{x_n \choose y_n}= lim_{n \to \infty} (2x_n+y_n^2)$.

I hope this is not too wordy but I would appreciate if someone could tell me if my thoughts on that topic are correct.

Comment: A single sequence does not tell you whether a function is continuous. You need *all* possible sequences. Single sequences can only possibly tell you that a function is *discontinuous* at a point.

Comment: @Allawonder, thanks for the remark I have edited my question.

Comment: Your difference quotient for $D_xg(x_0,y_0)$ is incorrect: by your own definition of $g$, $g(x,y_0)=x^2+xy_0^2$ when $x\ne x_0$, which I assume that you don’t want to be equal to $h(x,y_0)$. Also, how did you come up with the value $1$ for this derivative? By the continuity hypothesis, $g(x_0,y_0)=h(x_0,y_0)=x_0^2+x_0y_0^2$, so $D_xg(x_0,y_0)=2x_0+y_0^2$, no?

Comment: @amd, thanks. I corrected the differential quotient. I simply set the partial derivative at ${x_0 \choose y_0}$ equal to $1$. There is no further reasoning behind this because I only wanted to focus on the general understanding not on the details. I hope that I haven't expressed it too misleadingly.

Comment: You can’t arbitrarily set the value of the partial derivative at $(x_0,y_0)$ to some other value, though. Your definition of $g$ and its continuity at that point force the partial derivative there to have a specific value. I think that you might need to back up a bit and construct a different $g$.

Comment: @amd, yes you are absolutely right. I hope this issue didn't cause too much confusion. I adjusted $g$ and $D_xg{x_0 \choose x_0}$ accordingly.